# How can I make these menu items I created look right in IE7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

On this website:

[www.americaspoeticsoul.com](http://www.americaspoeticsoul.com)

I made a menu. Now, I just looked at it in this IE7 and the menu looks horrible. See...

In Chrome and all other Good Browsers:

[image: Menu in Chrome]

And in Internet Explorer 7:

[image: Menu in IE7]

As you can see, it is all messed up in IE7. Here is the menu code:

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/guidelines/">Guidelines</a></li>
<li><a href="/poems/" class="current_link">Poems &amp; Commentary</a></li>
<li><a href="/contact/">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And the menu CSS:

```
/*Menu*/

#menu {
margin-bottom:5px;
}

#menu ul { /* remove bullets and list indents */
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#menu ul li {
float:left;
}

#menu ul li a {
padding:10px;
margin:2px;
background-color:#D41C1C;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:15px;
color:white;
width:300px;
border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-o-border-radius:10px;
}

#menu ul li a:hover {
padding:10px;
margin:2px;
background-color:#FF1C1C;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:15px;
color:white;
width:300px;
border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-o-border-radius:10px;
}

#menu ul li a.current_link {
padding:10px;
margin:2px;
background-color:#FF1C1C;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:15px;
color:white;
width:300px;
border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-o-border-radius:10px;
}
```

Does anyone know why IE7 is displaying the menu like this? And could you help me fix it?

Thanks in advance,

Nathan

Comment: IE7 and under sucks, works fine on IE 8.
IE in general sucks. You cant fix it, its the way IE interpret CSS

Comment: Do what andyb says, you'll never be able to fix the not rounded borders though :[

Comment: @mazlix That isn't actually true, you can get rounded borders in IE7/IE8 see my answer below.

Comment: i've never been so happy to be wrong!

Comment: @raym0nd I 100% agree. IE is a web designers enemy! (accept IE9) But IE9 actually works with my websites. I really hate the fact that alot of people use IE8. They just don't know anything about the web obviously. They probably don't even know CSS3 exists.

Comment: @mazlix I'm going to use CSS3Pie as tw16 has mentioned.

Comment: @Nathan not everyone can upgrade IE or even use a non-IE browser. I would rather a functional menu over one with rounded corners with an overhead of css3 PIE. Bloating your code base with _unnecessary_ workarounds for IE7 only means you will have to take it out later and anyone visiting the site with IE receives a performance hit, as opposed to making a single property change from `float:left` to `display:inline`. Also note that css3 PIE is [not a silver bullet](http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the CSS that will fix your issue (but no rounded corners as not supported). I have set a width for `#menu` to stop the *contact us* folding over on itself, I have then removed the unnecessary widths from the `<a>` and set them to display: block. This means the nav items show up the same size as in other browsers (if you want rounded corners see after css):

```
/*Menu*/

#menu {
    margin-bottom:15px;
    width:450px;
}

#menu ul { /* remove bullets and list indents */
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu ul li {
    float:left;
}

#menu ul li a {
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    margin:2px;
    background-color:#D41C1C;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:15px;
    color:white;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -o-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
}

#menu ul li a:hover {
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    margin:2px;
    background-color:#FF1C1C;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:15px;
    color:white;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -o-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
}

#menu ul li a.current_link {
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    margin:2px;
    background-color:#FF1C1C;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:15px;
    color:white;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -o-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

On a side note I rearranged your border radius properties so that the standard is last. The reason for this is so that modern browsers use the standard property instead of an older prefixed one.

Now there are ways to make IE7 and IE8 produce round corners and some are incredibly simple. I would recommend using http://css3pie.com/. All you do is upload their file to the root of your directory and put the `behavior: url(PIE.htc);` property in to your rule with the CSS3 properties i.e. border radius. If you read the site you will see it supports quite a few.

Comment: I really disagree with adding workarounds for old browsers when the menu is perfectly functional without rounded corners. [Progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) is the way to do this.

Comment: @andyb On the one hand I agree with you... a site should be designed so that it degrades gracefully. On the other hand if all we were wanting from websites was 'functionality' then the web would be a much more ugly/boring place. When I design a site, that is how I want it to look in all browsers, or as close as I can get it without going over board. Generally well written CSS will get the layout as you want it, and I can't see what the problem is if you can add the enhancements simply/easily to your code so that it better matches your original design.

Comment: css3 PIE adds a performance overhead to the site for IE, requires another file to be downloaded **and** all PIE'd elements need to be `position:relative`, which may not fit with the page design. Content is what is important. I don't visit a site for it's rounded corners, I visit it for it's content. If my browser can render rounded corners and the developer/designer thought to put them in then that's a bonus. I'm in the [Progressive enhancement > graceful degradation](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement) camp.

Comment: @andyb: As I said above I am basically in both camps. I design for graceful degradation but if I can easily add the extra touches without too much hassle I will do it. In a scenario where it played up with a layout or was causing problems I would not use it.

Comment: @tw16 Thanks so much! This works great. I know that the border-radius isn't as important as making it functional, but before it wasn't even functional and had no padding at all. And I think having a border-radius looks nicer than squares. Who agrees? 

I'm just replaced the current menu CSS with this new one that you provided in my stylesheet and it is much better. 

Thanks!

P.S. I don't use IE7 nor do I have IE7, I just have the Google Chrome "IE7 Extension" so I can see how my sites look in it.

Comment: @Nathan I disagree. Did you read my comments about the overhead and unnecessary complexity of css3 PIE? You don't use or have IE7 but are adding IE specific workarounds to make it "look nice".

Comment: @nathan: Happy I could help. Could you please mark/check the tick next to my answer to accept it as the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: @andyb Lots of users coming to the site are sadly using IE 8 or below (mostly IE7) . That is why I'm going to use CSS3Pie. But, your method `display:inline;` works perfectly. I don't know which one to choose :/ I voted yours and tw16's up but I don't know which one would be the _best_ answer. 

I might just make each navigation item have a background-image, the text wont be part of the image, only the style of each item (the box with rounded corners). So I may just do that instead. What do you guys suggest?

Comment: @nathan: I commented on andyb's answer, `display: inline` messes up the padding + margins you already set as they are no longer block level elements. My solution keeps your original spacing between the items and are more predictable to change. Bg images for nav, is a solution that was used a lot, it becomes personal preference. The images would increase the loading time ever so slightly and are less flexible in terms of different widths. I would go with my solution looking to the future, and if worried about css3pie(overhead is tiny on your site!) just allow the design to degrade gracefully.

Comment: @nathan: Plus my solution fixes a number of css issues you had including wrongly ordered border-radius properties and redundant `<a>` widths.

Comment: @tw16 I didn't know border-radius properties had to be in order, thanks for the tip and thanks for fixing it. 

By the way this site actually isn't mine, I built it for someone.

Comment: @tw16, @Nathan I did try my `display:inline` before posting. There were **no** margin/padding issues that I could see. It doesn't need to be a block level element. The css3 PIE _performance_ overhead should **not** be ignored. That said, you clearly have done the research and know that you get significant traffic from IE7 so I understand the desire to make it look the same (even if I disagree with it). Proliferating workarounds for older browsers only extends the life of these browsers as users see no reason to upgrade!

Comment: @andyb That's true. I'm going to display a message on there saying "You are using an outdated version of your browser. We highly recommend you to upgrade to a better and more secure browser such as Google Chrome." (and Google Chrome will be a link to download) I am sick of people using IE8 or down. But it is impossible to stop them I guess. Some companies make their employees use IE6 or 7 which is just stupid. I did also try your `display:inline;` and it worked without padding/margin issues. But tw16 did some extra edits in my code. Your code still works though.

Comment: Just so you know as tested in FireFox 5, when switching to `display:inline` the spacing between all of the nav items expands as well as pushing the main content area further down.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to just change

```
#menu ul li {
    float:left;
}
```

to

```
#menu ul li {
    display:inline;
}
```

for all browsers. It fixes the IE7 problem and still displays perfectly fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE8 (that I tested). `display:inline` is a lot less problematic than `float:left` in my experience and is the correct approach here. You want a set of inline list items, not a set of floated elements outside of normal page flow.

The rounded corners will not work on IE7 or IE8 though so if you *really* need to make it identical on all browsers you will have to use an alternate solution, either with images, JavaScript or one of many other workarounds or IE specific shenanigans.

In my opinion, it is not worth the extra code and hassle (and UX testing). The menu is perfectly functional without rounded corners. [Progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) is what *every* web developer should be practising and if anyone tells you that the site needs to look the same in all browsers, point them here - http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/ and if they still insist that it look identical then double the development cost to support their out-of-date browser and attitude! `</rant>`

Comment: Just a side note about `display:inline`. I find that it plays havoc with your margins and spacing.

Comment: Not really since the "havoc" is [by design](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/) and there are way more IE bugs with floated elements, although I do admit most of them were fixed in IE7 (but not all).

Comment: I know it is by design. But the point is if you have already set all your margins and paddings to work based on block level elements, your design is going to be affected by switching over to inline. In an ideal world Microsoft would force an update for everyone to IE9 and all older sites could still render in their respective compatibility modes. Then we would never have to worry about all the ridiculous peculiarities of old IE versions! http://www.ie6countdown.com/ They should kill all of them off!

Answer (score 0):

just try the following CSS.. might be helpful. And I agree that 'andyb' says IE doesn't support rounded corners.. Good Luck!

```
#menu ul { /* remove bullets and list indents */
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#menu ul li {
float:left;
}

#menu ul li a {
padding:10px;
margin:2px;
background-color:#D41C1C;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:15px;
color:white;
border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-o-border-radius:10px;
float:left;

}

#menu ul li a:hover {
padding:10px;
margin:2px;
background-color:#FF1C1C;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:15px;
color:white;
border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-o-border-radius:10px;
    display:block;
}

#menu ul li a.current_link {
padding:10px;
margin:2px;
background-color:#FF1C1C;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:15px;
color:white;
float:left;
border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-o-border-radius:10px;
}
```

Comment: Your right, IE8 and down doesn't support CSS3 features, but I am going to use what tw16 recommended, CSS3Pie which will allow me to have CSS3 features in non-CSS3 browsers. (See his answer below)